# Java Gregorian calendar to specific format

Tags: java, android, eclipse, date

I've been trying to format a gregorian calendar to a specific format as to fulfill a webservice but I don't know how to make it elegant.
Right now I'm trying to format by getting the hour of minute and parsing them but it looks horrible.
I need to format it as xsd:dateTime 2001-10-26T21:32:52, 2001
Any helps appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the javadoc of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: You could use a SimpleDateFommat, using a format like "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, yyyy" or simular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be straight foward to adjust the format to what you need ... 
this produces "2013-06-08T20:56:25Z"

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String time = timeFormat.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class ConversionExamplesDate {

  // Convert from String to date
  private void stringToDate() {

    try {
      Date date1;
      date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse("05/18/05");
      System.out.println(date1);
      Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("05/18/2007");
      System.out.println(date2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  // Convert from millisecs to a String with a defined format
  private void calcDate(long millisecs) {
    SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
    Date resultdate = new Date(millisecs);
    System.out.println(date_format.format(resultdate));
  }

  private void writeActualDate(){
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    Date creationDate = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
    System.out.println(date_format.format(creationDate));
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConversionExamplesDate convert = new ConversionExamplesDate();
    convert.stringToDate();
    convert.calcDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    convert.writeActualDate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [joda](http://joda-time.sf.net):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
String str = fmt.print(dt);
```